# OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow|AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can't read the 'grant_type' parameter using Postman, but I can read it normally and get the return using OkHttp, how can I make Postman work properly.
I am using the Postman configuration from the documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

[image: Postman]

[image: OkHttp]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send grant_type neither in params nor in headers. Those should be sent in body params then only it will work.

Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token client_id, scope and redirect_uri params can be sent as query params. where as grant_type, code and client_secret should sent in body params.

please see the postman image sample below .

[image]

If you are trying to get the refresh token , you have to add
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the header,
[image]

Hope this resolve your issue , please let us know if you have any query

Thanks

---

If the answer was helpful , kindly click on upvote mark the answer as verified  ,so that it will help others as well .

Comment: I did send the grant_type parameter in the body. The screenshots of postman and okhttp are attached to my question, which are indeed the same as yours, and the postman configuration is still in the document, so I imported it directly. However I found that you are in form-data and I am sending parameters in x-www-form-urlencoded, maybe that is the problem, I am trying to send parameters in form-data.

Comment: I tried to modify x-www-form-urlencoded to send the parameter from-data, unfortunately it did not read the grant_type, then I changed the Content-Type in the Headers: application/x-www-url-form- urlencoded is removed, it can read the grant_type and refresh the token normally, and now the grant_type attribute can also be sent normally with x-www-form-urlencoded.

Thanks！

Comment: ![Snipaste_2022-08-17_09-42-13.png](https://s2.loli.net/2022/08/17/v9PXJqcbVDIWzBy.png)![Snipaste_2022-08-17_09-43-51.png](https://s2.loli.net/2022/08/17/kKRH1lGCgMXAdoy.png)

Comment: Thanks for posting the screenshot of postman , good to hear that your problem has been solved , please let me know if you have any further query. thanks